# Get index creation date from SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I find the create date of an index. I am using `SQL2008 R2`.
I checked `sys.indexes` but it does not have a create date so I joined the query with `sys.objects`.  The thing is that the object id for an index and the table containing that index is same.

I am using this query...

```
select i.name, i.object_id, o.create_date, o.object_id, o.name
from sys.indexes i 
join sys.objects o on i.object_id=o.object_id 
where i.name = 'Index_Name'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have to find out the latest index that is created on a particular table

Comment: The property dialogue for an index provides no information about the index's creation date. That might be a sign that the date cannot actually be obtained.

Comment: @AndriyM, yes that true....so their is no way through which we can obtain the index creation date...

Answer (score 16):

For indexes that are constraints, then see [marc_s' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7580021/1501497)

For other indexes, you'd have to use STATS_DATE to get the creation time of the associated index (every index has statistics on it)

Something like (not tested)

```
SELECT STATS_DATE(OBJECT_ID('MyTable'), 
(SELECT index_id FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'Index_Name'))
```

This relies on the sys.indexes to [sys.stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177623.aspx) links

Edit: there is no way to find out as far as anyone can find out. Sorry.

Comment: `STATS_DATE` gives the time the stats were updated not created AFAIK

Comment: @Martin Smith: You are correct. I thought it gave both: don't have SQL Server installed here *and* didn't read MSDN...

Answer (score 14):

Simple query to list indexes in descending date (of statistics) order.
This date is the sate of last statistics update, so is only reliable for recently created indexes.

```
select STATS_DATE(so.object_id, index_id) StatsDate
, si.name IndexName
, schema_name(so.schema_id) + N'.' + so.Name TableName
, so.object_id, si.index_id
from sys.indexes si
inner join sys.tables so on so.object_id = si.object_id
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: If the index is on a view, you'll need to replace sys.tables with sys.objects.

Answer (score 7):

This is now quite a long dead thread but the below query from SQLPanda got me the info I needed on Azure SQL for a non clustered index:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS TableName, i.object_id, i.name, i.type_desc,o.create_date, o.modify_date,o.type,i.is_disabled
FROM   sys.indexes i
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type NOT IN ('S', 'IT')
  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 
  AND i.name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

Credit to http://www.sqlpanda.com/2013/10/how-to-check-index-creation-date.html

I just added the modified date since that was the info I was interested in.

Comment: This is wrong. It gives table's creation date not index's creation date.

Comment: Wrong. The modified date is the table's last modification date. Not related to indexes stats.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    i.name 'Index Name',
    o.create_date
FROM 
    sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON i.name = o.name
WHERE 
    o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND o.type IN ('PK', 'FK', 'UQ')
```

The `object_id` refers to the table the index is created on....

Comment: that is true but it will only give Create_Date for table no index

Comment: FKs are not indexes, are they?

Comment: Some of my indexes are not listed - They are unique index - but not unique constraints. How to get them listed?

Comment: I think that sys.objects.create_date is a creation date of table, a view eventualy, but not an index assinged to them. For me there is no separate field that keeps index creation date. So it leaves us with index statistics creation date.

Answer (score 3):

When PK or UK is created, SQL Server automatically creates unique index for that constraints. The create_date of those constraints will be the same as the create date for the corresponding indexes.

Since the sys.indexes view does not have create_date column it is absolutely useless for searching this kind of information. Furthermore, object_id column in this view will never refer to the corresponding constraint. It will point to the table the index belongs to.
The following test will demonstrate the point:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_T1
(
    COLUMN_1 INT NOT NULL, 
    COLUMN_2 INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TEST_T1 PRIMARY KEY (COLUMN_1)
)
GO
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

ALTER TABLE dbo.TEST_T1
    ADD CONSTRAINT UK_TEST_T1 UNIQUE (COLUMN_2)
GO

SELECT O.name, O.object_id, O.create_date, I.object_id, I.name AS index_name
FROM sys.objects AS O 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes AS I ON O.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE O.name IN ('TEST_T1', 'PK_TEST_T1', 'UK_TEST_T1')
```

The result is:

```
name        object_id   create_date             object_id   index_name
PK_TEST_T1  272720024   2015-03-17 11:02:47.197 NULL        NULL
TEST_T1     256719967   2015-03-17 11:02:47.190 256719967   PK_TEST_T1
TEST_T1     256719967   2015-03-17 11:02:47.190 256719967   UK_TEST_T1
UK_TEST_T1  288720081   2015-03-17 11:02:48.207 NULL        NULL
```

So, if you want to see create_date for PK or UK indexes there is no need to join with sys.indexes. You should select from sys.objects:

```
SELECT name, object_id, create_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name IN ('PK_TEST_T1', 'UK_TEST_T1')
AND type IN ('PK', 'UQ')
```

The result is:

```
name        object_id   create_date
PK_TEST_T1  272720024   2015-03-17 11:02:47.197
UK_TEST_T1  288720081   2015-03-17 11:02:48.207
```

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [YourDB Name]
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Table_Name varchar(200)
DECLARE @Index_Name varchar(200)
DECLARE @Index_Type varchar(50)

DECLARE Indx_Cursor CURSOR
STATIC FOR
            select s_tab.name as Table_Name,
                   s_indx.name as Index_Name,
                   s_indx.type_desc as Index_Type
            from sys.indexes s_indx
            inner join sys.tables s_tab 
                    on s_tab.object_id=s_indx.object_id
            where s_indx.name is not null;
            
OPEN Indx_Cursor
    IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
        BEGIN 
            FETCH NEXT FROM Indx_Cursor INTO @Table_Name,@Index_Name,@Index_Type

WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INDEX_HISTORY(table_name,index_name,Index_Type,Created_date) 
    SELECT  @Table_Name,@Index_Name,@Index_Type,
            STATS_DATE(OBJECT_ID(@Table_Name), 
            (SELECT index_id FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE name = @Index_Name))as Index_create_Date
                    
                    FETCH NEXT 
                          FROM Indx_Cursor 
                          INTO @Table_Name,@Index_Name,@Index_Type
                END
        END

CLOSE Indx_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Indx_Cursor

select distinct * from index_history
```

But the main problem with indexes is that when we rebuild or reorganize indexes then the index creation date gets changed to the date when the index was last rebuilt or reorganized.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    crdate, i.name, object_name(o.id)
from 
    sysindexes i
join 
    sysobjects o ON o.id = i.id 
where 
    i.name = 'My_Index_Name'
```

Comment: That's going to give you the created date of the table, not the index.

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005** or newer, you should use the catalog view in the `sys` schema - use `sys.indexes` (instead of `sysindexes`) and `sys.objects` or better yet: `sys.tables` (instead of `sysobjects`)