# Query for the creation date of indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get the creation date of indexes?  I'm using the following query to identify indexes based on their name but would like to see a date and time stamp of their creation.  I'm hoping there is a way to join the sysindexes table to another via indid to get these details.

```
SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE name LIKE '%CustomReport%'
```

Right clicking on the index in ssms object explorer allows viewing the properties but a create date and time stamp is not included.

Comment: Is there a field associated with the index to tell when it was created? Such as `ID|Username|dateCreated`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get index creation date from SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579932/get-index-creation-date-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you join back to sys.objects there's a create date there.

```
select o.create_date
from sysindexes i 
inner join sys.objects o 
  on i.id = o.object_id
```

Comment: yes - but the create date appears to be the table creation not the index creation.

Comment: Hmm, you're correct...it looks like there's no way to find out after doing some more research. See this related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579932/get-index-creation-date-from-sql-server

Comment: wow - that's bad news, but thanks for the link to the information.

Comment: * inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id = i.object_id